# Unable to set values to a spinner. Shows "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1" during app installation

Tags: java, android, xml

Trying to create a simple project that fetches data from the database and feeds to the spinner drop-down. But getting the below-mentioned error(android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1). I am using a database helper class for the same. Can someone please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
                                                                        Process: com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner, PID: 5993
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner/com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
                                                                         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:305)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:400)
                                                                            at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:389)
                                                                            at com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner.MainActivity.loadSpinner(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                            at com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et_name;
    Spinner spinnerContactName;
    Button btn_add;
    SQLiteController controller;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        spinnerContactName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_data);
        btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        controller = new SQLiteController(this);
        controller.Open();
        loadSpinner();
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new MyAsnkTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadSpinner() {
        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
        controller.Open();
        Cursor c = controller.readData();
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            String name = getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Contact_name));
            dataList.add(name);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_view, R.id.txt_name, dataList);
        spinnerContactName.setAdapter(adapter);
        controller.close();
    }

    private class MyAsnkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("please Wait");
            pd.setMessage("loading");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            controller.Open();
            String name = et_name.getText().toString();
            controller.insertData(name);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            loadSpinner();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify SQLiteController parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

SQLiteController.java

```
package com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

/**
 * Created by Sumeet on 20-04-2017.
 */

public class SQLiteController {
    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public SQLiteController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SQLiteController Open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertData(String name) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.Contact_name, name);
        db.insert(DBHelper.Table_name, null, values);

    }

    public Cursor readData() {
        String allColumns[] = new String[]{DBHelper.Contact_id, DBHelper.Contact_name};
        Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.Table_name, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Sumeet on 20-04-2017.
 */

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String Table_name = "table_contact";
    public static final String Contact_id = "id";
    public static final String Contact_name = "name";

    public static final String dataBase_name = "contacts_db";
    public static final int dataBaseVersion = 1;

    public static final String Create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_name
            + "("
            + Contact_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            + Contact_name + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            + ")";

    private static final String Drop_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + Table_name;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dataBase_name, null, dataBaseVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Create_table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Drop_table);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }
}
```

spinner_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

context_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.sumeet.sqlitespinner.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to call `getString()` on the `Cursor` inside the loop in `loadSpinner()` – `c.getString(...)`.

Comment: Well, that did resolve the error and app was installed. But i am a little confused because for any new entry that I make and press the add button the value "1" is displayed in the spinner dropdown.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks a lot for your response. But I could not understand what changes you meant actually. Can you please point out the mistake again?

Comment: In the `loadSpinner()` method, change to this: `String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Contact_name));`. You're just adding `c.` in front of `getString()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, :) Works like a charm.